# Caching remote repository via wheel files

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, python-wheel

I would like to create a wheel file which could pull the change from remote repository in Bitbucket. The remote repository requires password. 
Did anyone use the binary wheel to do such operation?

Comment: Why? Is it a `pip`-installable dependency?

Comment: Yes, I intended to find way to replace the "clone to local device and pull the latest change to it periodically".